# Viewing what's in a model in Rails concole without Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, irb, pry

I know that one can use Pry to see what a model in composed of but is there a way to see the various attributes of a model in the Rails console without Pry? What is the command?

I know I can go looking at the migration but I'd rather stay in the command line where possible.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. That got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From script/console or irb you can just issue the name of the class and it will return the attributes.

For instance, with a Post model:

```
>> Post
=> Post(id: integer, title: string, body: text, created_at: datetime)
```

Comment: That's it. Also Object.attribute_names works w/o showing the types. Thank you.